# Is there any database about the abundance of proteins in urine of healthy patients?

Tags: proteins, database, cancer

I have a dataset about adundance of urine proteins from cancer patients. I would like to compare these abundance levels to healthy patients' urine proteins. However I don't have any data with healthy patients. Is there any database about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the UK Biobank dataset, then they have urine data for healthy individuals.

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41588-020-00757-z